# Make timeago update live

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins, timeago

I'm using the [timeago plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) and I need to make it **update automatically so that if new times are passed to the page, it will update them**.

Here's the default JQuery we're asked to put on our pages:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
```

My current issue is that, when I pass a new time from a PHP file using Ajax, it won't use the timeago plugin (it stays as the date, `2013-10-28`, rather than `1 second ago`, etc).

Here's the Ajax I have right now:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/timeago.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'post.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $(".container").html(data.message);
            }
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});

</script>
```

The `post.php` file called by Ajax:

```
<?php

    $code = '<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>';

    $array = array('message' => $code);

    echo $array;

?>
```

When the Ajax function is called, it returns the `$code` HTML, but it prints out `July 17, 2008` on the page, rather than `5 years ago`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify some load time either in your class (`loaded` or `modified`, perhaps), or a date/time in the `title` attribute of the element. Check your HTML

For example, this:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

will become this:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">about 5 years ago</abbr>
```

Comment: My current issue is that, when I pass a new time from a PHP file using Ajax, it won't use the timeago plugin (it stays as the date, `2013-10-28`, rather than `1 second ago`, etc).

Comment: If you're applying the `timeago` plugin at DOM ready, then it will be attached to all those elements that exist at that time. If you load new elements into the DOM with an AJAX call, `timeago` won't apply to them unless you specifically apply it.

Comment: How would I specifically apply it? I added part of my code in my post.

Comment: Adding `$(".container abbr.timeago").timeago()` as the last line in  your `success` function should do it. I haven't tested this.